# How to rebind $(image).load() when the src of the image changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Notice the `.load()` event in the following code.

```
var img; 
var path = "/theimage.jpg";

$(document).ready(function () {

    img = new Image;

    img.src = path;

    $(img).load(function () {
        redraw(0);
        zoom(-2, 1.7, false);
    });
});
```

This event fires successfully when the image loads...

But how can I get that `.load()` event to fire *again* if later in the life cycle of the page (say when the user clicks a link) I change the `src` of `img` to a completely new path (new image)?

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't fire when you set the `.src`?

Comment: It does fire the first time, but if I change the src of img (same object) later in another location it doesn't seem to fire a second time.

Comment: Your image could be cached by your browser, therefore you're just setting a new (in-memory) image and applying it to nothing.

Comment: Check out [jQuery's documentation for .load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) which mentions caveats when using `.load` with images. Basically, it's unreliable, not consistent, doesn't bubble, and doesn't work with cached files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load` event will fire by itself again after the entire new image is loaded.

Comment: Only if he is using the exact same image element that the event was bound to. I don't see where he is actually appending that `img` element to the DOM.

Comment: @KevinB You don't have to append it to the DOM for the image to be loaded, that's how image preloading is done, or was done 15 years ago

Comment: @JuanMendes Right, but the load event is bound to `img`, if `img` isn't moved to the dom, changing the src of some other img on the dom that uses the same src as `img` wont make `img`'s load event happen. That's what I was trying to say. Of course, he could change the global `img` var's src and get the load event to happen.

Comment: @KevinB What led you to believe that is what the OP was asking?

Comment: @JuanMendes Nothing in his code pointed to how he was changing the `.src` or what object he was changing the `.src` of.

Answer (score 2):

Combining what duri and Roko have said.

The load event does fire if you set the `.src` after the initial load. http://jsfiddle.net/2wWDN/

If the image is cached, the event will still fire again, at least it was true in the jsfiddle I created above

Comment: Also, if you first bind the load event, and then change the src, it will fire the first time regardless of the image being cached

Comment: To be clear, the image would only be cached if it was the same path, right?

Comment: @libertas No, it would be cached if you had the same path loaded previously loaded anywhere else, even a different page, it's a global browser cache